# Google Apps Script гиперссылка как и функцией IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью **Google Apps Script** реализовать перенос данных таким же образом как и функцией **IMPORTRANGE**,чтобы значением ячейки было текст или число и при этом гиперссылка сохранилась.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCjBU.jpg

Comment: Пожалуйста, просклоняйте правильно слова в предложениях - ничего не понятно.

Comment: _отредактировал

Comment: Это вопрос из тостера https://toster.ru/q/686169 Интересный вопрос. Думаю, что только через Sheets API. И то надо пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Через метод `copyTo(destination)`данные будут вставляться с сохранением гиперссылки (и остальным форматированием, согласно документации).
Пример:

```
// The code below copies the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 5);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6));
```

Описание метода в документации - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=ru#copytodestination